# How do I find all the views used by Phalcon?

Tags: php, phalcon

How do I find all the views used by phalcon for a single request after rendering the request? I want to know the Action view, controller layout and Main layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a listener to the view component:

```
<?php

//Setting up the view component
$di->set('view', function() {

    // Create an event manager
    $eventsManager = new Phalcon\Events\Manager();

    // Attach a listener for type 'view'
    $eventsManager->attach('view', function($event, $view) {
        if ($event->getType() == 'beforeRenderView') {
            echo $view->getActiveRenderPath(), PHP_EOL;
        }
    });

    $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
    $view->setViewsDir('../app/views/');

    // Bind the eventsManager to the view component
    $view->setEventsManager($eventsManager);    

    return $view;

}, true);
```

More info here: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#view-events